# Importing (non-library) .bam files in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a `.bam` file which I want to import into R. Later, I want to be able to import several (150+) large files in R and process them. Experimental data importing from libaries works, but not my own dataset from my `D:/ drive`.

I tried with using the package `Rsamtools` and used the following commands:

```
> filename <- "1658_AR_hisat2_sorted.bam" #Change filename as necessary
> (bf <- BamFile(filename))
```

Which generates the following output:

```
class: BamFile

path: 1658_AR_hisat2_sorted.bam

isOpen: FALSE 

yieldSize: NA 

obeyQname: FALSE 

asMates: FALSE 

qnamePrefixEnd: NA 

qnameSuffixStart: NA
```

But when I then run:

```
> bam <- scanBam(bf, param=param)
```

> Error in value[3L] : 
>     failed to open BamFile: file(s) do not exist:
>     '1658_AR_hisat2_sorted.bam'

Why is the file not present? Could it be that the file is too large?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
bam <- scanBam(BamFile(file.choose() ),
               param=param)
```

and select your file

```
# list of .bam
dat_bam <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = ".bam", all.files = FALSE,
           full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE,
           ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE)
# import all
list_bam <- lapply ( dat_bam , scanBam )
```

Comment: I get the error 

`Error in is(param, "ScanBamParam") : object 'param' not found` 

Can I just remove `param`? And how do I deal with it on a large scale?

Comment: check this https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/Rsamtools/inst/doc/Rsamtools-Overview.pdf they say you can process them in chunk

Comment: I'm more referring to the fact that I have 150+ files and that I'm not very eager to select them by hand.